I want to get gender value using radio button male for Male and female for Female via FOR OF
I am checking Male button but getting Female value.
I want to Male value while checking male button.
<script>
    let regUsers = [];
    let regForm = document.querySelector("#regForm");
    let allRegInput = regForm.querySelectorAll("input");
    let regBtn = regForm.querySelector("#regBtn");

    regForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = {};
        for(let elem of allRegInput){
            key = elem.name;
            data[key] = elem.value;
        }
        regUsers.push(data)
        console.log(regUsers)
        
    })


Assuming from button means Radio Buttons.
Your for loop is looping over all the radio buttons you have. Since in your case it seems Female might be last radio button, it is overwriting the Male value because we have key with input as its name.
Example below to see the issue:


    let regUsers = [];
    let regForm = document.querySelector("#regForm");
    let allRegInput = regForm.querySelectorAll("input");
    let regBtn = regForm.querySelector("#regBtn");

    regForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = {};
        for(let elem of allRegInput){
            key = elem.name;
            
            data[key] = elem.value;
            console.log(`key: ${key} and value: ${elem.value}`)
        }
        regUsers.push(data)
        console.log("------------")
        console.log(regUsers)
        
    })
  <form id="regForm">
        <input type="radio" name="input" value="Male">Male
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="input" value="Female">Female
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" id="regBtn">Click Me</button>
        <br>
      </form>



You need to used this regForm.querySelector("input[name='input']:checked"); to get value of selected radio button.


let regUsers = [];
let regForm = document.querySelector("#regForm");
let regBtn = regForm.querySelector("#regBtn");

regForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = {};
    let selectedRadio = regForm.querySelector("input[name='input']:checked");

    if (selectedRadio) {
        data[selectedRadio.name] = selectedRadio.value;
        console.log(`key: ${selectedRadio.name} and value: ${selectedRadio.value}`);
    }

    regUsers.push(data);
    console.log("------------");
    console.log(regUsers);
});
  
      <form id="regForm">
        <input type="radio" name="input" value="Male">Male
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="input" value="Female">Female
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" id="regBtn">Click Me</button>
        <br>
      </form>
      



